Question on Presto-Prestissimo ExchangeSource
I'm ramping up on presto-prestissimo and velox and I was asking myself:

what the difference between BroadcastExchangeSource and PrestoExchangeSource is? The first sounds a little like being involved in shuffle/joins

what the counterpart of that source is? There doesn't seem to be a sink?



a) PrestoExchangeSource is the operator used for regular http/https based exchange. BroadcastExchangeSource is used for files based broadcast. This was added for Native Presto on Spark project. https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/19858
b) The counterpart of a remote source is a remote TableScan.
